# Why ist my custom content scroller disappearing after scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scrollbar

I am using custom content scroller from http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/. Here is my problem:

[image: My Problem]
After integrating the scrollbar the usage is faulty. When I drag the scrollbar with the mouse, the whole content disappears after I finished dragging. Before the content of the whole dropdown-menu was still active.

How can I get the dropdown-menu to stay active? Timeout? Overlay?

EDIT:
I included the custom content scrollbar in my header with:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" 
href="/templates/EvoOriginal/themes/evo/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/EvoOriginal/js/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"></script>
```

JQuery was already included.

In my footer I added the script to customize my dropdown-menu´s

```
<script>
    (function($){
        $(window).on("load",function(){
            $(".dropdown-menu, .Dropdown, .nav-panel .nav .nav").mCustomScrollbar({
            theme:"dark-2",
            scrollButtons:{
                enable:true
        }});
        });
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

After this the problem occurs.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "_Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") __must include__ the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and __the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself__'. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]_"

Comment: Could you share your code (perhaps a JSFiddle) so we can see what's going on?

Comment: Sry, I did not add any Code because I thought people who could help me, would understand the general problem of a disappearing scrollbar + they saw the jquery custom content scroller webpage. Post is edited.

Comment: @trevorp https://jsfiddle.net/b0znc92d/ I shared my jquery mCustomScrollbar.css and jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js